# programmatically clicking the "Image Submit"

Tags: browser

I am trying to make an app on .NET to click the "submit" button on a web page.  Basically the app is filling out forms and clicking submit.  Most of the pages work but some of them they have a graphic like "NEXT" and "PREVIOUS".  There is no submit type control on the web page. The source code that I can see doesnt show that there is a JS to call or anything. The web source just looks like its a graphic, and nothing else.

I am trying to find out how I would click on the graphic or find out what its doing like calling javascript or something so I can emulate it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look harder. Or give link of such a page

Comment: http://nutritiondata.self.com/  this is an example but not the actual page I am working on. I see that this one does the same thing however.  enter the food name at the top and then how do you click?

Comment: Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

The page could be adding the click event handler somewhere else in javascript. If you are looking for a automation solution [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) would be another program to look at to automate firefox or IE using .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it in .NET? I write simple automation programs like this all the time in [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/), it's very good for this sort of thing.

Comment: The reset of the app is in .net already.  http://nutritiondata.self.com/  this is an example but not the actual page I am working on. I see that this one does the same thing however.  enter the food name at the top and then how do you click?

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to do this?